# What is property tab in query console in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am trying my hands on Marklogic Query console. I understood what Document is , Format and Collections and their use. I am unable to understand why property tab is used for? when clicked on it, it shows the property for the particular document. but why do we need properties? whats the use? Please give me a real time scenario.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Properties Tab in Query Console would display the XML document properties fragment for the context document in the database; properties are optional, so nothing will show if there are no properties, and are usually used to store metadata about the associated document, and they share the same URI. Properties can be accessed in XPath using the `property::` axis. Properties documents can also stand alone at a URI with no associated document. JSON documents can have properties, too, but they must be stored as XML. Element indexes can be created as well on properties document elements. There is an API on properties that includes `xdmp:document-properties` to access properties, `xdmp:document-add-properties` to create properties on a document, and `xdmp:document-set-properties` which can be used to create standalone properties documents.

Comment: Properties can be convenient to keep metadata separate, and particularly useful for annotating binaries as mentioned be ehennum as well. There are some pros and cons though. Resolving queries against properties usually comes with a performance penalty, since it takes an extra join between fragments. You get double amount of fragments. Properties are not managed temporally, and can only contain XML. We typically advice people to use the envelope pattern, rather than document properties. It is explained in detail here: https://www.marklogic.com/blog/envelope-design-pattern/

Answer (score 3):

A properties fragment is a sidecar document fragment that keeps metadata about a document separate from the content of the document.  Common uses include:

- Properties projected out of binary files so they are searchable
- Timestamps on documents including bitemporal documents
- Workflow state for documents including the state for CPF (the Content Processing Framework)

For more detail, see:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/properties#id_19516

Hoping that helps,